# I don't work comments and forms are not displayed

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to make comments on the site, but when I start the server, I do not see the forms. I create a simple blog in which a person can post likes and comment, but the problem is that when i add a comment form, they simply do not appear.

P.S

And excuse me for my English I am from another country and I don’t know English very well

post.html main template

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class=" text-info">{{object.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p> {{object.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
        <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
    </div>

        <h4>Comments</h4>


    <form action="{% url '' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {% if CommentModel %}
        {% for CommentModel in comments %}
          {{ CommentModel.WhoAreYou }} <br>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from .forms import CommentForm



class ArticlesList(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'



class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/post.html'





def GetComments(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    else:

        form = CommentForm()

        comments = CommentModel.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'news/post.html', {'form': form, 'comments': comments})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', ArticlesList.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('aboutUs', views.aboutUs, name='aboutUs'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py it's models for posts and for comments

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CommentModel(models.Model):
    WhoAreYou = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py form for fields

class CommentForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = CommentModel
    fields = ('WhoAreYou',)
```

Answer (score -1):

you've write `class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm)` in forms.py:

```js
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    comment = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
      model = CommentModel
      fields = ('WhoAreYou',)
```

I guess it'll works.

Comment: What kind of library do you need to import?